# SimpleDateFormat does not give correct date

Tags: java, simpledateformat

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class myTests {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MMM-dd", Locale.US); 
        try {
            Date sortingDate = (Date)formatter.parse("2017-Jul-13");
            System.out.println("Sorted Date is:"+sortingDate);

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Result is

> Sorted Date is:Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 PST 2017

Why wont it show date i gave 2017 Jul 13
Can you please let me know.

Thanks
Abe

Answer (score 7):

uppercase Y is   Week year. What you Need is lowercase y = Year.

So Change `new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MMM-dd", Locale.US);` to `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd", Locale.US);` and you should get the correct result.

For more informations see the [javadoc of SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

If you are using java8, you should Change to [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) and the new DateTime API